# Angular2: Custom Select Component and Reactive Forms

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, angular2-forms

I am running into trouble with Reactive Forms and creating a custom select component.

I need to create some custom select component.

I've looked at multiple answers on Stackoverflow which involve providing an implementation of "ControlValueAccessor". Those look like they'd work but are very heavyweight for what I need.

I've also played around with extending "SelectControlValueAccessor" but it seems as though that isn't a very common thing. If it isn't common, I question whether it is the correct way to approach my problem.

Basically, I need a custom select component which automatically makes a service call and works with reactive forms.

This is similar to what I'm looking to do:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'customer-select',
    styleUrls: ['./customer-select.component.css'],
    templateUrl: './customer-select.component.html'
})
export class CustomerSelectComponent extends SelectControlValueAccess implements OnInit {
    customers: ICustomer[];

    constructor(
        private render: Renderer2,
        private elementRef: ElementRef,
        private customerService: CustomerService,
    ) {
        super(render, elementRef);
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.customerService.getCustomers()
           .subscribe((response: IApiResponse<ICustomer[]>) => {
                    this.customers = response.Data;
                   this.customers.sort(this.getFuncToSortMostUsedToDefaultOrdering());

                   // additional logic goes here 
                },
               (err: any) => console.log(err),
                () => console.log('getCustomers() retrieved workflows')
           );
    }

    private getCompareToStrings(firstEl: string, secondEl: string) {
        if (firstEl < secondEl) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (firstEl > secondEl) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    private getFuncToSortMostUsedToDefaultOrdering() {
        // Assuming that we have two customers.
        return (firstElement: ICustomer, secondElement: ICustomer) => {
            return SomeLogicHere.Compare(firstElement, secondElement)
    }

}
```

Here's the HTML Code:

```
<!-- Need the formControlName somehow passed in ---> 
<select id="customer" class="form-control" formControlName="customer">
    <option *ngFor="let customer of customers" [ngValue]="customer">
        {{customer.CustomerNumber}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Don't hesitate to mention any details that I might be missing. Or maybe questions or design discussions that I've overlooked.

Perhaps I could use composition over inheritance and compose the 'SelectControlValueAccess' while still implementing 'ControlValueAccessor'?

Any trivial solutions that don't involve too much hanky panky? It just seems like the rest of the solutions are so complicated for such a trivial thing.

EDIT: The reason I'm doing this is because this 'customer-select' will be used in so many places in the application.

Also, I will have to do this for like 5 other selects which is why I don't like so much code for something so trivial.

EDIT:

**I think this code is working if anyone has any input on this code, perhaps something I overlooked, then please share: NEVERMIND BROKEN**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'customer-select',
    templateUrl: './customer-select.component.html',
    providers: [
        {
            provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
            useExisting: forwardRef(() => CustomerSelectComponent),
            multi: true
        }
    ]
})
export class CustomerSelectComponent extends SelectControlValueAccessor implements OnInit {
    customers: ICustomer[];

    constructor(
        private render: Renderer2, 
        private elementRef: ElementRef,
        private dataService: DataService,
        private fb: FormBuilder
    ) {
        super(render, elementRef);
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.dataService.getCustomers()
            .subscribe((response: IApiResponse<ICustomer[]>) => {
                    this.customers = response.Data;
                    // Additional Logic
                },
                (err: any) => console.log(err),
                () => console.log('getCustomers() retrieved workflows')
            );
    }
}
```

The HTML:

```
<select id="customer" class="form-control">
    <option *ngFor="let customer of customers" [ngValue]="customer">
        {{customer.CustomerNumber}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

We created a custom select component for Bootstrap 4 in Reactive Form Control which implements ControlValueAccessors. Here is the code, modify based on ur needs.

**Component:**

```
import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  Input,
  Output,
  EventEmitter,
  SimpleChanges,
  forwardRef,
  ElementRef,
  ViewChild,
  OnChanges
} from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'input-customselectcontrol',
  templateUrl: '...',
  styleUrls: ['......'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      multi: true,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => SelectFormControlComponent)
    }
  ]
})
export class SelectCustomFormControlComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor {
  @Output() dropdownEventUpdate: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  public selectedDropDownValue = '';
  @Input() dropDownListArray: Array<any>;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  writeValue(value: any) {
    if (value) {
      const matchObj = _.find(this.dropDownListArray, function(o) {
          return o.text === value;
        });
        this.selectedDropDownValue = matchObj && matchObj.text ? matchObj.text : '';
      }else {
      this.selectedDropDownValue = 'Select';
    }
  }

  propagateChange(time: any) {
    console.log(time);
  }

  registerOnChange(fn) {
    this.propagateChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched() {}

  // tslint:disable-next-line:use-life-cycle-interface
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {

  }

  onDropDownChange = function(id, value) {
    this.selectedDropDownValue = value;
    this.dropdownEventUpdate.emit({
      id: id,
      text: value
    });
  };
}
```

**Template:**

```
<div ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block custom-btn-color col-md px-0 w-100" #inputDropdown="ngbDropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-outline-primary custom-height px-2 dropdown-custom w-100 custom-drop-down-text-override pr-4 text-left" [ngClass]="{'input-errorCls': isRequiredError}" id="sortMenu" ngbDropdownToggle>{{selectedDropDownValue}}</button>
  <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby=" sortMenu" class="w-100">
    <button class="dropdown-item px-3 custom-drop-down-text-override" *ngFor="let value of dropDownListArray" (click)="onDropDownChange(value.id, value.text);$event.stopPropagation();">{{value.text}}</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Calling Template Code:**

```
<input-customselectcontrol (dropdownEventUpdate)="updateTopicDropdownEvent($event, i)" [dropDownListArray]="TopicsArray"  name="selectdropdownvalue" formControlName="selectdropdownvalue"></input-customselectcontrol>
```